# Centering a tabularx created through a custom command

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I have renewed the `\item` command inside a new environment and I have added inside this environment a `tabularx` so that all items are properly aligned (see images below).

My issue is that I am unable to center the resulting tabularx inside the column of the page. I have tried to encapsule everything in a table environment and using the `\centering` command, but none of this give the desired result (or it doesn't keep the alignment of each `\item`). Any ideas?

Here is what I currently have:

[image]

And this is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

The code of the main document is:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{class}

\begin{document}

\begin{factlist}
    \item{Spanish}{Good level}
    \item{English}{Good level}
    \item{French}{Intermediate level}
\end{factlist}\\

\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

And the `.cls` class is:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{class}
\newcommand{\myFontSize}{10.0}

\LoadClass[fontsize= \myFontSize pt]{scrartcl}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\RequirePackage[hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm,twocolumn,columnsep=1cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox,tabularx,makecell,setspace,lipsum}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newenvironment{factlist}{%
    \newdimen\unbaseline
    \unbaseline=\dimexpr-\baselinestretch\baselineskip\relax
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
    \textsc{##1} & {\raggedright ##2\medskip\\}\\[\unbaseline]}
    \tabularx{0.7\linewidth}{rX}}
    {\endtabularx}
```

Comment: unrelated but don't do `\newdimen\unbaseline` inside the macro that is a global allocation and uses up one register each time you use the list, just allocate that once in the preamble

Comment: `\begin{center}\tabularx`  ... `\endtabularx\end{center}` ?

Comment: Thanks for the first comment, I will modify it. As for the second one, I have already tried that and it throughs and error...(I cannot add braces inside the ones of `\endtabularx`)

Comment: What about `{factlist}{\center`... `{\endtabularx\endcenter}`?

Comment: @leandriis I just tried that and still throughs an error (if you want I can edit the question and show you the log)

Comment: do you want `tabularx` at all? I suspect not, it will never look centred as your second column is wide (to force the table to be .7\linewidth` but the text in the column is short. Don't you just want a tabular so you can centre the actual width of the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can centre the `tabularx` but it will not look centred as the second column is artificially forced wide to make the table be .7\linewidth but there is no visible indication of the right hand edge. For tables without line breaking it os better to use `tabular`

I show `tabularx` and `tabular` variants here

[image]

```
\documentclass{class}

\begin{document}

\begin{factlist}
    \item{Spanish}{Good level}
    \item{English}{Good level}
    \item{French}{Intermediate level}
\end{factlist}

\begin{factlistb}
    \item{Spanish}{Good level}
    \item{English}{Good level}
    \item{French}{Intermediate level}
\end{factlistb}

\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{class}
\newcommand{\myFontSize}{10.0}

\LoadClass[fontsize= \myFontSize pt]{scrartcl}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\RequirePackage[hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm,twocolumn,columnsep=1cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox,tabularx,makecell,setspace,lipsum}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newenvironment{factlist}{%
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
    \textsc{##1} &\raggedright ##2\tabularnewline}%
    \centering\tabularx{0.7\linewidth}{rX}}%
    {\endtabularx\par\medskip}

\newenvironment{factlistb}{%
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
    \textsc{##1} &##2\tabularnewline}%
    \centering\tabular{rl}}%
    {\endtabular\par\medskip}
```

Comment: thats great! Thank you for the answer. Just to keep the result as the original one (in terms of  vertical spacing), you could simply add `\tabularnewline[5pt]` to the answer.